# Virtual Listview with pictures : How to fill all the column space with the picture

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to setup a listview with pictures.
As i have 3000+ items in that list i'm using the `VirtualMode`.
Here is my code :

```
     ImageList il = new ImageList();
        private void artistList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var art_list = from res in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Artist_ID"))
                           .Select(x => new { artiste = x.Select(p => p.Field<string>("artiste")).First(), fp = x.Select(p => p.Field<string>("file_path")).First() })
                           .OrderBy(x=>x.artiste)
                           select res.fp;
            fp = art_list.ToList();
            int buffer = 20;
            il.ImageSize = new Size(90, 90);
            listView1.VirtualMode = true;
            for (int i = 0; i< buffer; i++)
            {
                il.Images.Add(i.ToString(), Globals.getMp3Image(fp[i]));
            }
            listView1.LargeImageList = il;
            listView1.VirtualListSize = fp.Count();
        }
        private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item == null) e.Item = new ListViewItem(e.ItemIndex.ToString());
            e.Item.ImageIndex = il.Images.IndexOfKey(e.ItemIndex.ToString());
        }
```

I'm using a buffer of 20 and i'll try to implement a cache mechanism later.
My issue is the visual result i'm getting, here is a picture :

[image]

I have several issues here :

1/ the number below the picture should be the index, but why is it displayed ?

2/ i'd like to expand the picture to the to avoid the white spaces in the 4 directions (there is some white spaces in the left)

3/ i'd like to avoid the horizontal scrollbar (but i think this issue is linked to #2)

Here is the Designer info : (the view is set to LargeIcon)

```
 this.listView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.listView1.HideSelection = false;
        this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.listView1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
        this.listView1.ShowGroups = false;
        this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 657);
        this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listView1.RetrieveVirtualItem += new System.Windows.Forms.RetrieveVirtualItemEventHandler(this.listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem);
```

Of course i've tried to set the Size of the `listview` at 90 but it's worst.

Comment: See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2

Comment: The text is there because you set it: `e.Item = new ListViewItem(e.ItemIndex.ToString());`. Change it in `e.Item = new ListViewItem();` to remove it. To hide the horizontal bar, make the ListView larger (with images of 90px, to ~155px). Or owner-draw it. The *problem* here is not the 3000+ items (the ListView has not problem at all to handle them), it's the possible 3000+ images that an ImageList is storing. You're loading just 20 now. That's what you need to *virtualize*. Meaning, avoid keeping all those images in memory.

Comment: You could pre-build a `List<ListViewItem>` (as shown here: [Why the Items of a Virtual ListView that are not visible don't have index?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719931/7444103)), for indexing purposes, remove the ImageList and draw each item when requested yourself, so you can also better define its position. Then, use a class object to buffer a suitable number of images, based on the current index position (since now you have one), give back the current Image requested and one of the cached Images after. Dispose and rebuild the cache when the current Index goes out of scope.

Comment: @jdweng, it's a nice control but doesnt allow for virtual list. I think i really need that feature here

Comment: Jimi, thank you (forgot about the declaration of the ListviewItem). I'm looking forward a way to get the pictures nicely put with no white space, once i'll be able to do it, i'll investigate the cache feature (got a good lead in your post) but dont want to spend time on it if i get that kind of results.

Comment: Well, as already mentioned, you can OwnerDraw your ListView, so you can paint the Images where you like. Otherwise, send a [`LVM_SETICONSPACING`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-seticonspacing) message to the ListView before adding any image (maybe in a Form's constructor or OnHandleCreated override). E.g., if your Images are sized to `90x90`, you could set the `LOWORD` (left padding) to `95` and `HIWORD` (top padding) to `100`. I only use custom ListView controls and this featrure is set as a public `IconPadding` property. You have to handle DPI changes, though

Comment: All Virtual means is you have additional methods (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode?view=netcore-3.1)  The first link I provided shows how to create the ListView.  So you can put the two examples together.

Comment: Well, look at that, I searched `"ListView Icon spacing iconspacing"`, out of curiosity, and these came out: [ListView Tile layout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2754416/7444103) -- [ListView spacing issue with View: List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45878186/7444103) -- (more) --- You want just the first link.

Comment: Thanks Jimi, managed to customize it nicely using `LVM_SETICONSPACING` ! Follow up question, can you lead me to how to align the text (below the picture) on the left ? it seems eveyrthing's complicated using these Listview ... thanks